# Building binary package R

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to make a standalone executable so that my scripts can be run without development tools. I have created multiple R scripts containing different functions and have been using a `main.r` script to connect the other scripts. I have been using RStudio and using Source on each file to add them to the Global Environment and finally using Source on my main file to start executing my program. When attempting to build a binary package through:

```
Build > Build Binary Package
```

I was getting the error:

```
ERROR: The build directory does not contain a DESCRIPTION 
file so cannot be built as a package.
```

So I created a package and now the error I get is

```
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in reorderPopulation(pop_fitness_list) : 
  could not find function "reorderPopulation"
Error : unable to load R code in package 'EAtsp'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'EAtsp'
* removing 'C:/Users/Ryan/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsXbv0j/temp_libpath27ec59515c59/EAtsp'
Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Can someone explain to me how to fix this problem?

EDIT: I have since added `roxygen` comments to each of my functions and they are all displaying within the `NAMESPACE` file but still have the same issue.

These are the files my R directory contains:

```
fitness.r
initDataset.r
main.r
operators.r
selection.r
```

The functions within `fitness.r` can be found from `main.r` with no problem so I moved the `reorderPopulation` function which was previously in `selection.r` to `fitness.r` and it can be found. Why can the functions inside the `selection.r` file and possibly the others not be found?

Comment: You need to have the code for the function `reorderPopulation` in the package. [This book is a good place to start](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/)

Comment: The code is within the package believe it or not. Inside my R directory within the package is all of the R scripts. I actually looked at the beginning sections of the book before posting this, it's how I know that I am aiming to create a binary package

Comment: Is it exported? Is it in the namespace? Is it documented? Are you using Roxygen? Is the DESCRIPTION file error still relevant? (If not, I suggest removing it from your question.) It's very difficult to debug code without seeing any code...

Comment: A first package can be tricky. I would suggest building an empty package first, then adding code little bit at a time, checking and building at each step.

Comment: Yeah no kidding. Like I said I'm completely new to this so I just assumed creating the package would pretty much take care of it. So the answer to all your above questions is no. I would have thought I would define somewhere which order to load files in?

Comment: Creating the package will take care of it. But creating a package, while much easier than it used to be, is still not trivial. Load order doesn't matter. My guess is that you use that `reorderPopulation` code in what, a vignette or examples section? But it's not exported. You'll probably want to export most if not all of the functions in your package.

Comment: I also bet that when this error is corrected, you'll have many many more. Because you've never built a package and you're trying to build one with a bunch of code all at once. Start small, go little by little. As-is, it's like your bringing a novel  to a 30-minute writing workshop hoping for feedback. It's too much.

Comment: In my main file I reference some functions from another file and those work fine. However inside the while loop I also reference some functions from other files but those all get the same "could not find function" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from @r2evans I have managed to find a solution to the problem.

My `main.r` file was just a bunch of function calls with no function wrapping them. So I wrapped the function calls in a function and the function now looks as follows:

```
mainFunction <- function() {

    source("R/initSetup.r")
    initSetup()

    ... 
}
```

`initSetup.r` contains more `source()` calls to the other files that I use. The program is then run using the command mainFunction() in the R console

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing reproducible, so I'll go through a hacked example that works, perhaps you can use it as a template for explaining what is different and why yours should still work.

### `./DESCRIPTION`

```
Package: Porteous96
Title: This package does nothing
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person('r2evans', email='r2evans@ignore.stackoverflow.com', role=c('aut','cre'))
Description: This package still does nothing
Depends: R (>= 3.3.3)
License: MIT
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
```

(Go ahead and try to send an email there ... I don't think it'll bug me ...)

### `./NAMESPACE`

After `create`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: fake comment so roxygen2 overwrites silently.
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
```

After `document`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(reorderPopulation)
```

(Regardless, this file needs no manually editing, assuming you are either using `roxygen2` with its `#' @export` clause, or you are using the default "export almost everything" without `roxygen2`.)

### `./R/reorderPopulation.R`

```
#' Do or do not
#'
#' (There is no try.)
#' @param ... any arguments ultimately ignored
#' @return nothing, invisibly
#' @export
reorderPopulation <- function(...) {
  cat("do nothing\n")
  invisible(NULL)
}

unorderPopulation <- function(...) {
  reorderPopulation()
  cat("should not be found\n")
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

### `./R/zzz.R`

I added this file just to try to "find" one of the exported functions from within this package.

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  reorderPopulation("ignored", "stuff")
}
```

I can get away with assuming the function is available, per [`?.onLoad`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-hooks.html):

> Note that the code in '.onLoad' and '.onUnload' should not assume
>   any package except the base package is on the search path.
>   Objects in the current package will be visible (unless this is
>   circumvented), but objects from other packages should be imported
>   or the double colon operator should be used.

### Build and Execute

I actually started this endeavor with a template directory created by starting in the intended directory and running:

```
devtools::create(".")
# Creating package 'Porteous96' in 'C:/Users/r2/Projects/StackOverflow'
# No DESCRIPTION found. Creating with values:
# Package: Porteous96
# Title: What the Package Does (one line, title case)
# Version: 0.0.0.9000
# Authors@R: "My Real Name <myreal@@email.address.com> [aut,cre]"
# Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
# Depends: R (>= 3.3.3)
# License: Call for information, please
# Encoding: UTF-8
# LazyData: true
# * Creating `Porteous96.Rproj` from template.
# * Adding `.Rproj.user`, `.Rhistory`, `.RData` to ./.gitignore
```

However, you can easily just use the samples I provided above and move forward without calling `create`. (It also includes some other files, e.g., `./.gitignore`, `./Porteous96.Rproj`, and `./.Rbuildignore`, none of which are required in the rest of my process here. If you have them and they have non-default values, that might be good to know.)

From there, I edited/created the above files, then:

```
devtools::document(".")
# Updating Porteous96 documentation
# Loading Porteous96
# do nothing
# First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
# Writing NAMESPACE
# Writing reorderPopulation.Rd
```

(The reason you see "do nothing" above and below is that I put it in a function named `.onLoad`, triggered each time the library is loaded. This includes during `devtools::document` and `devtools::install` as well as the obvious `library(Porteous96)`.

One side-effect of that is that a `./man/` directory is created with the applicable help files. In this case, a single file, `reorderPopulation.Rd`, no need to show it here.

```
devtools::install(".")
# Installing Porteous96
# "c:/R/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
#   --quiet CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/r2/Projects/StackOverflow/Porteous96"  \
#   --library="C:/Users/r2/R/win-library/3.3" --install-tests 
# * installing *source* package 'Porteous96' ...
# ** R
# ** preparing package for lazy loading
# ** help
# *** installing help indices
# ** building package indices
# ** testing if installed package can be loaded
# *** arch - i386
# do nothing
# *** arch - x64
# do nothing
# * DONE (Porteous96)
# Reloading installed Porteous96
# do nothing
```

For good measure, I close R and re-open it. (Generally unnecessary.)

```
library(Porteous96)
# do nothing
```

(Again, this is dumped to the console because of `.onLoad`.)

```
reorderPopulation()
# do nothing
unorderPopulation()
# Error: could not find function "unorderPopulation"
Porteous96:::unorderPopulation()
# do nothing
# should not be found
```

### Wrap-Up

I'm guessing this does not solve your problem. It highlights about as much as I could glean from your question(s). Perhaps it provides enough framework where you can mention salient differences between my files and yours. Though answers are not meant for pre-solution discussion, I think it is sometimes necessary and useful.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem through just using a source call at the start of my main file to load my other files. This is probably bad practice but it works for my case. As for your explanation I don't see anything majorly different from what I done, perhaps just the ordering of how it was done as my scripts were created not as part of a package originally.

Comment: This suggests that you have code in files in `./R/` that are outside of function declarations. This is generally very bad practice, as just loading the file can have unintended consequences. However, if it works for you (and you don't publish it), then so be it. You might want to provide your own answer detailing (briefly) what you did to remedy the problem, in case others have the same symptoms. (I argue a little more detail about the problem would still be useful, since I still am not clear what is going on.)

Comment: Oh that might actually be the problem. My main.r file is really just a series of function calls with no function wrapping them. I'll go try out this approach