# How to use other R scripts within my package

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have been using RStudio to develop my code so far and have functions spread across different files and a `main.r` file to control the flow of the program which calls these other functions. I have been using the Source command to add all these functions to my environment so that they can be seen from `main.r` and this worked fine.

Now I am trying to create a package but I get the error when trying to load it:

```
Loading EAtsp
Error in reorderPopulation(pop_fitness_list) (from main.r#24) : 
could not find function "reorderPopulation"
```

`main.r` can correctly see the functions before the `while` loop in my code but cannot see any of them inside the `while` loop. The function `reorderPopulation` is defined in a file separate from `main.r`. I have tried using `roxygen2` to comment my functions making sure to include the `@export` tag and the functions all correctly show in the `NAMESPACE` file.

My question is what is causing this problem and how can I prevent it next time?

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779254/building-binary-package-r)?

Comment: Tried to explain it a bit better but it is the same question since I still have the same problem

Comment: You should delete one of them. (I propose deleting this one.) If you have more information, then edit your first question with relevant updates. Please don't open an identical question.

Comment: I tried to delete the other one and assumed it would be deleted but I see your point