# Downloading R on Linux for multiple clients

Tags: r, linux

I've created a program that runs in R that I plan on distributing among a lot of other people. Currently the R script is ran completely automatically and behind the scenes with one .sh script which is exactly how it is intended to be. I'm trying to make it so theres no need for client intervention. The R script itself loads the packages and installs them if they aren't present which takes away the task of them installing the packages themselves.
Is there a way I can provide a folder within my Application's folder that they already download that contains R-script and its dependencies so the code can use that location of Rscript to compile and run the R-program I have created. The goal is to be able to download it and run without the need of internet connection to download R and maybe even the programs required packages if possible.
Any help or ideas is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that process you want called "creating binary package". Binary is programs (like EXE files) which can run directly on target CPU without any interpreter software (like Python interpreter for python scripts, or Java VM for java applications). I'm not so familiar with packaging of R programs but I found some materials regarding this issue:

1 - [Building binary package R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779254/building-binary-package-r)

2 - https://seandavi.github.io/post/build-linux-r-binary-packages/

3 - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486508-Building-Testing-and-Distributing-Packages

Second link assumes Linux as target system. Opposite to interpreted languages, binary files often OS dependent (Linux, Windows, or Mac). I, personally, don't know how compatible are packages between Linux systems with different library sets.
Please comment if you find some information misleading, I'll correct the answer.